# ImmutablePair and Pair compilation error working in decompiled class

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have created following Minimal, Reproducible Example

I have getting compilation error

Eclipse [Eclipse compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJBVd.png)  . "The type Pair does not define getValue(Object) that is applicable here"

IntelliJ says [IntelliJ compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVNak.png)

I am trying to use part of the logic from a jar file so I have not written this logic, but this code is working fine from decompiled class.

I have put this logic in my own class and getting compilation error

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
public class TestClass
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Map<ObjectAttributesValueContainer, Set<CompareAttribute>> differences = null;

        final Map<CompareAttribute, Collection<ObjectAttributesValueContainer>> differentObjectsForAttributes = (Map) differences
                .entrySet().stream().flatMap((entry) -> {
                    return ((Set) entry.getValue()).stream().map((attr) -> {
                        return new ImmutablePair(entry.getKey(), attr);
                    });
                }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getValue, (pair) -> {
                    return new HashSet(Collections.singleton(pair.getKey()));
                }, (a1, a2) -> {
                    a1.addAll(a2);
                    return a1;
                }));
    }

}


class CompareAttribute
{
    private String qualifier;
    private String group;

    public CompareAttribute(final String qualifier)
    {
        this.qualifier = qualifier;
    }

    public CompareAttribute(final String qualifier, final String group)
    {
        this(qualifier);
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getQualifier()
    {
        return this.qualifier;
    }

    public void setQualifier(final String qualifier)
    {
        this.qualifier = qualifier;
    }

    public String getGroup()
    {
        return this.group;
    }

    public void setGroup(final String group)
    {
        this.group = group;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (o == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (o.getClass() != this.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            final CompareAttribute that = (CompareAttribute) o;
            if (!this.qualifier.equals(that.qualifier))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (((CompareAttribute) o).getGroup() == null && this.group == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return ((CompareAttribute) o).getGroup() != null && this.group != null ? this.group.equals(that.group) : false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = this.qualifier.hashCode();
        if (this.group != null)
        {
            result = 31 * result + this.group.hashCode();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.qualifier + (this.group != null ? '@' + this.group : "");
    }
}

class ObjectAttributesValueContainer
{
    private final Object object;
    private final Map<CompareAttribute, Object> attributeValues;

    public ObjectAttributesValueContainer(final Object object)
    {
        this.object = object;
        this.attributeValues = new HashMap();
    }

    public Object getObject()
    {
        return this.object;
    }

    public Map<CompareAttribute, Object> getAttributeValues()
    {
        return this.attributeValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: after removing the initial `{` I'm getting this `error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K,U}).collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getValue, (pair) -> {` Did you try to compile this exact code?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to compile above class class.strange... I don't get the same issue when I have this class inside my project. If I create a new java project with commons-lang3 in it, it gives Type Safety warning.And which initial { you are removing, I don't have to remove any curly braces

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't need to remove one either. My mistake. I ran your code with a different name and added a curly brace myself. I can't get your code to compile. This is all about the types. If it was my code, I'd start with all the warnings.

Comment: Example: `this.attributeValues = new HashMap();` needs to be `this.attributeValues = new HashMap<>();` or `this.attributeValues = new HashMap<CompareAttribute, Object>();` An other thing is your cast to `(Map)` I don't think that will work. You need to make sure your map fits with the result.

Comment: Even if I suppress warnings, it gives me error for missing method for Pair. Also, can I do it without using lambda?

Comment: The warnings are there to warn you about the error that might happen. Don't suppress them, fix them :) lambdas are just easy ways to implement an interface. You can always implement them instead. The reason your code is not compiling is because java is confused about the types that you are collecting. That's what it's saying with `cannot infer ... T,K,U` what is T, K and U?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast to a `map` of a particular type, so I removed that. Your

```
return ((Set) entry.getValue()).stream().map((attr) -> {...
```

can never work, because `flatmap` must return a `stream`.

I've made a few assumptions, and added some types. Now at least it compiles. First I removed the warning:

```
public ObjectAttributesValueContainer(final Object object) {
  this.object = object;
//  this.attributeValues = new HashMap();
  this.attributeValues = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Then I kept track of the types:

```
final Map<CompareAttribute, Collection<ObjectAttributesValueContainer>> 
  differentObjectsForAttributes = 
  differences
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap((entry) -> 
                   entry.getValue() // Set<CompareAttribute>
                   .stream()
                   .map((attr) -> {return new ImmutablePair<ObjectAttributesValueContainer,CompareAttribute>
                                                            (entry.getKey(), attr);}
                 ))
        // now we have a stream of ImmutablePair<ObjectAttributesValueContainer,CompareAttribute>
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getValue, 
                                   (pair) -> {return new HashSet<ObjectAttributesValueContainer>
                                                               (Collections.singleton(pair.getKey()));
                                             }, 
                                   (a1, a2) -> {a1.addAll(a2);
                                                return a1;
                                               }
                                   ));
```

Comment: works standalone, but still getting this    [yjavac] Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<CompareAttribute,Collection<ObjectAttributesValueContainer>> when I am building my original code using ANT.

Comment: @EulerRule That's probably from somewhere else. The same thing applies. You can't cast like you tried to do. So if you have a map, make sure it's with the correct types before assigning it. I believe I fully answered your question and solved the problem in it.

Comment: you are right, the standalone code compiled..I tried making it an answer, but it days "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @EulerRule I had completely forgotten about those rules, sorry. Types are always confusing until you get used to them. I think of them as String or Integer, and then I know that if I create a `Map<Integer,String>`, then I cannot `put(Object,Object)` into it. If you're using raw types, you'll always hit this problem. But usually later :( That's why you need to compile without warnings.

Comment: @EulerRule It's just a guess, but I think somewhere you're doing this `Map differences = new xxxxMap();` but you have to do this instead `Map<CompareAttribute, Collection<ObjectAttributesValueContainer>> differences = new xxxxMap<>();` <- this last empty `<>` is important. If you don't use it, it's a raw type.